# Incrementing count variable without waiting the upper line of code to finish

Tags: python, pygame

So,I have this code.
I want to increment count variable by not waiting  this two audio files to process completely.
In my code below it is  very obvious that count variable  will be incremented only if the two audio files  done playing.
Is there any idea on playing it on background or can I call a subprocess here ?

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.mixer.init()
count = 0 
while(True):
    pygame.mixer.Sound('song1.ogg').play()
    time.sleep(0.54)
    pygame.mixer.Sound('song2.ogg').play()
    time.sleep(0.52)
    count +=1
    print(count)
```

Comment: what is the purpose of ur counter?

Comment: Why not just move the line of code so the counter is incremented first?

Comment: I want to run them in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the code is waiting for the sleep commands to finish. Generally, you never want to use `sleep` statements in your main thread, as your program will lock up. You can move the logic for playing sounds to a new [Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread).

```
import time
import pygame
from threading import Thread

def play_sounds():
    pygame.mixer.Sound('song1.ogg').play()
    time.sleep(0.54)
    pygame.mixer.Sound('song2.ogg').play()
    time.sleep(0.52)

pygame.mixer.init()
count = 0 
while(True):
    Thread(target=play_sounds).start()
    count +=1
    print(count)
```

Comment: It does increment , but audio files are overlapping

Comment: @max2p As I'm not sure exactly what you are attempting to accomplish with your sounds, I've edited my answer to provide a more general use case using Threads.

Comment: Thanks for your time,  I am currently testing your code , there's an error in my system on running your code , I will fix it first

Comment: I'm adding two lines : import time and
pygame.mixer.init(), this time audio files are not audible but count var is incrementing

Comment: I have overlooked the incremented time of count variable , it is still waiting for the play_sound to finished

Comment: @max2p it is working fine on my machine. Do you have more in your code than this?

Comment: I just copy your whole code, replacing only the 2 audio files, it does increment the count value in every millisecond, but there's no audio on it unless I change Thread(target=play_sounds).start()  to Thread(target=play_sounds()).start() , this time 2 audio files able to play but incrementing the count variable will wait until the play_sounds() finishes its execution time